# How to view Berkeley DB contents?

Tags: database, file-format, berkeleydb

I have a copy of addressbook from Nokia N900 and it's a Berkeley DB file. How can I view it's contents?

```
$ file addressbook.db 
addressbook.db: Berkeley DB (Hash, version 8, native byte-order)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `db-util`. There are several in Ubuntu Software Center (for example `db5.3-util`). The latest version via command line:

```
sudo apt-get install db-util
```

After installing all you need to do is:

```
db_dump addressbook.db
```

Description of an old version from USC:

[image]

Comment: It didn't really work for me, but that's more of this DB specifics.   https://github.com/tersmitten/n900-backup-extractor

Comment: @int_ua then you should upvote your own answer (but we would appreciate if you did not link-dump but make it a real answer ;)

Comment: The code in question is quite big and under version control. I don't think it's a good choice to include it, do you? What else can be done?

Comment: P.S. I can't upvote my own answers :)

Comment: oh wait; you can accept it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For this specific DB I have to use this script:

https://github.com/tersmitten/n900-backup-extractor

( http://blog.tersmitten.nl/how-to-export-your-contacts-from-a-n900-backup-directory.html )

Answer (score 1):

If you have postfix installed, try

```
postmap -s <database-file-name>
```

For example, with the two files virtual and virtual.db, where virtual is the text file from which virtual.db was made with makemap, use

```
postmap -s virtual
```

Note that you do not have to specify the .db extension.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't verify it now, sorry.